# not able to prevent local job runner from running

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I am trying to fill up the hbase table from a java program using HTable and LoadIncrementalHFiles on Hadoop-1.

I have a fully distributed 3 node cluster with 1 master and 2 slaves.

Namenode,jobtracker are running on master and 3 datanodes,3 tasktrackers on all 3 nodes.

3 zookeepers on 3 nodes.

HMaster on master node and 3 regionservers on all 3 nodes.

My core-site.xml contains :

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>

<property>
  <name>fs.default.name</name>
  <value>hdfs://master:54310/</value>
</property>
```

mapred-site.xml contains :

```
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>master:54311</value>
</property>
```

But, when I run the program it gives me below error :

```
15/08/06 00:11:14 INFO mapred.TaskRunner: Creating symlink: /usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/mapred/local/archive/328189779182527451_-1963144838_2133510842/192.168.72.1/user/hduser/partitions_736cc0de-3c15-4a3d-8ae3-e4d239d73f93 <- /usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/mapred/local/localRunner/_partition.lst
15/08/06 00:11:14 WARN fs.FileUtil: Command 'ln -s /usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/mapred/local/archive/328189779182527451_-1963144838_2133510842/192.168.72.1/user/hduser/partitions_736cc0de-3c15-4a3d-8ae3-e4d239d73f93 /usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/mapred/local/localRunner/_partition.lst' failed 1 with: ln: failed to create symbolic link `/usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/mapred/local/localRunner/_partition.lst': No such file or directory
15/08/06 00:11:14 WARN mapred.TaskRunner: Failed to create symlink: /usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/mapred/local/archive/328189779182527451_-1963144838_2133510842/192.168.72.1/user/hduser/partitions_736cc0de-3c15-4a3d-8ae3-e4d239d73f93 <- /usr/local/hadoop/TMPDIR/mapred/local/localRunner/_partition.lst
15/08/06 00:11:14 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
15/08/06 00:11:15 INFO util.ProcessTree: setsid exited with exit code 0
15/08/06 00:11:15 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : org.apache.hadoop.util.LinuxResourceCalculatorPlugin@35506f5f
15/08/06 00:11:15 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
15/08/06 00:11:15 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/08/06 00:11:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
15/08/06 00:11:17 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
15/08/06 00:11:17 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't read partitions file
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner.setConf(TotalOrderPartitioner.java:116)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
     at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewOutputCollector.<init>(MapTask.java:677)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:756)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:214)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File _partition.lst does not exist.
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:397)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:251)
     at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getLength(FileSystem.java:796)
     at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1479)
     at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1474)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner.readPartitions(TotalOrderPartitioner.java:301)
     at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.partition.TotalOrderPartitioner.setConf(TotalOrderPartitioner.java:88)
     ... 6 more
```

Few lines from my code :

```
    Path input = new Path(args[0]);
    input = input.makeQualified(input.getFileSystem(conf));
    Path partitionFile = new Path(input, "_partitions.lst");
    TotalOrderPartitioner.setPartitionFile(conf, partitionFile);
    InputSampler.Sampler<IntWritable, Text> sampler = new InputSampler.RandomSampler<IntWritable, Text>(0.1, 100);
    InputSampler.writePartitionFile(job, sampler);
    job.setNumReduceTasks(2);
    job.setPartitionerClass(TotalOrderPartitioner.class);

    job.setJarByClass(TextToHBaseTransfer.class);
```

Why its still running the local job runner and giving me "Can't read partitions file"?

What am I missing in the cluster configuration?

Comment: are you sure regarding permission issues?